# perform multiple sql queries when clicking a submit button on PHP Page

Tags: php, mysql, submit, onsubmit

I have a PHP page, that on clicking the submit button process a few MySQL queries.

in MySQL PHPMyAdmin the query works 100% and both queries execute. However, when in my PHP Code the queries do not execute.

Any help would be appreciated, I bet this is a simple one for decent PHP coders.

Thanks in advance Ryan.

My Code is:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "hulamin_hulamin", "Hulamin2011")or die("cannot connect");    
    mysql_select_db("hulamin_loc")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="SELECT `dispatcharea`,`customer`,`casenumber`,`weight` from loaddetails where loadid = 0 order by dispatcharea";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Plan Local PMB Delivery - Step 2
</title>
</head>
<html>


<table border=0>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="form1" method="post">
                <table border=1>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=150>Dispatch Area</td>                        
                        <td width=300>Customer</td>  
                        <td width=150>Case Number</td>
                        <td width=100>Weight</td> 
                    </tr>
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['dispatcharea']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['customer']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['casenumber']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['weight']; ?></td>
                    </tr>    

<?php
  }
?>      
</table>            
    <input name="Next" type="submit" id="Next" value="Next">                

<?php
if($_REQUEST['Next']=='Next') {
    {
        $sql="update loaddetails set loadid= (select max(loadid)+1 from loadcounterid) where loadid=0; update loadcounterid set loadid= (select max(loadid) from loaddetails) where loadid>0;";

        $final=mysql_query($sql);
        if($final)
        {
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=planlocalpmbstep3.php\">";
        }
    } 
}

?>
</table>

</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks again,
Ryan

Comment: why don't you run the two queries in two separate calls to mysql_query?

Comment: Hu @mishu, can you adivse me how to do this on the existing code? how do I hav two actions for one button click? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is likely to be your problem

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Should be

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

To refer to them as

```
echo $rows['dispatcharea'];
```

EDIT:

You also need to split both of your queries up in to two separate queries, because you cannot run two queries in one mysqli_query() tag.

You will need to split them as shown below:

```
 // First update query
 $sql1="update loaddetails set loadid= (select max(loadid)+1 from loadcounterid) where loadid=0";

// Second update query
$sql2="update loadcounterid set loadid= (select max(loadid) from loaddetails) where loadid>0";

// Run both queries independently
$final_query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$final_query2 = mysql_query($sql2);

// Check for query success
if ($final_query1 && $final_query2)
{
   // Success running the queries
}
else
{
   // Unsuccessful running the queries
}
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_array by default returns both numeric and associative arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: It's a true point, but that is just because the default result type is 'MYSQL_BOTH'.  It doesn't deem the content is not useful, it's still worth noting that the specific function is available.

Comment: may be, but definitely not in the answer

Comment: Hi, the output returns correctly from the array. its the mysql query that does not update. any advice?

Comment: Please refer to the edit and code addition.  You cannot run two queries (even if separated by a semi colon) using a single mysql_query() function.

Answer (score 4):

According to the PHP docs, [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) doesn't support multiple queries. PHPMyAdmin is probably separating the queries before executing them. Try splitting your query into two parts. (Also, the PHP docs say that you shouldn't end mysql_queries in semicolons, but it doesn't appear to hurt.)

Comment: You are right @arxanas, PHPMyAdmin does break it down into two queries.  how can I break it down into two parts? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute multiple queries at once, you can change over to using `mysqli` functions.

There is a mysqli function `mysqli_multi_query()` that can be used to execute multiple queries at once.

Please refer to:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Here's a rough rewrite of the code using mysqli_multi_query() in an object oriented style:

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'hulamin_hulamin', 'Hulamin2011', 'hulamin_loc');
    $sql = "SELECT `dispatcharea`,`customer`,`casenumber`,`weight` from loaddetails where loadid = 0 order by dispatcharea";

    $result = $link->query($sql);
    $count = $result->num_rows($result);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Plan Local PMB Delivery - Step 2
</title>
</head>
<html>


<table border=0>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="form1" method="post">
                <table border=1>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=150>Dispatch Area</td>                        
                        <td width=300>Customer</td>  
                        <td width=150>Case Number</td>
                        <td width=100>Weight</td> 
                    </tr>
<?php
    while($rows = $link->fetch_array($result)){
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['dispatcharea']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['customer']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['casenumber']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['weight']; ?></td>
                    </tr>    

<?php
  }
?>      
</table>            
    <input name="Next" type="submit" id="Next" value="Next">                

<?php
      if($_REQUEST['Next']=='Next'){
 {
                            $multi_sql = "update loaddetails set loadid= (select max(loadid)+1 from loadcounterid) where loadid=0;";
                            $multi_sql .= "update loadcounterid set loadid= (select max(loadid) from loaddetails) where loadid>0";

                            $final = $link->multi_query($multi_sql);

                            if($final)
                            {
                            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=planlocalpmbstep3.php\">";
                            }                                            } 
                                }

?>
</table>

</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Disappointing to see this post voted down. `mysqli_multi_query` is ideal for this implementation - especially for executing multiple UPDATE mysql queries in one string.

Comment: Hi @Luke, I did some reading on the link you provided, how could I execute all the mysql statements on clicking the submit button? Thanks

Comment: @RyanSmith please see the code I've posted on this.  I've rewritten the whole piece of code (from a mysql point of view anyway).

Comment: Great to hear!  Did you split the query up, or end up using `mysqli` in the end?

Comment: Right now, I split the query up although I would like to try mysqli with more inserts. I have another page that I need to complete so will try with mysqli. Thanks @Luke.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4024/discussion-between-luke-coulton-and-ryan-smith)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would just post my complete code that is now working. thanks to all who replied to my question, it is greatly appreciated. It is really awesome to be a part of this community that is so responsive.

My code is:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password")or die("cannot connect");    
    mysql_select_db("dbname")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="SELECT `dispatcharea`,`customer`,`casenumber`,`weight` from loaddetails where loadid = 0 order by dispatcharea";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Plan Local PMB Delivery - Step 2
</title>
</head>
<html>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<center>
Load Number
</td>
<td>
<center>
Number of Cases
</td>
<td>
<center>
Load Weight
</td>
<td>
<center>
Other Detail
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td width=150>
<center>
<?php
$loadid = mysql_query('SELECT max(loadid)+1 FROM loaddetails');
if (!$loadid) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_result($loadid, 0);
?>
</td>

<td width=150>
<center>
<?php
$nocases = mysql_query('SELECT count(*) FROM loaddetails where loadid = 0');
if (!$nocases) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_result($nocases, 0);
?>
</td>

<td  width=150>
<center>
<?php
$weight = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(WEIGHT) FROM loaddetails where loadid = 0');
if (!$loadid) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_result($weight, 0);
?>
</td>

<td  width=150>
<center>

</td>

</tr>

</table>




<hr>
<table border=0>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="form1" method="post">
                <table border=1>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=150>Dispatch Area</td>                        
                        <td width=300>Customer</td>  
                        <td width=150>Case Number</td>
                        <td width=100>Weight</td> 
                    </tr>
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['dispatcharea']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['customer']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['casenumber']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['weight']; ?></td>
                    </tr>    

<?php
  }
?>      
</table>            
    <input name="Next" type="submit" id="Next" value="Next">                

<?php
 // First update query 
 $sql1="update loaddetails set loadid= (select max(loadid)+1 from loadcounterid) where loadid=0"; 

// Second update query 
$sql2="update loadcounterid set loadid= (select max(loadid) from loaddetails) where loadid>0"; 



      if($_REQUEST['Next']=='Next'){
      // Run both queries independently 
$final_query1 = mysql_query($sql1); 
$final_query2 = mysql_query($sql2); 

if ($final_query1 && $final_query2) 
{ 
   // Success running the queries 
   echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=planlocalpmbstep3.php\">";
} 
else 
{ 
   // Unsuccessful running the queries 
} 
}             

?>
</table>

</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```